# Modal Window Problem

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-2.0, modal-dialog

I am using modal window for my VB.NET program and i am trying to open this child modal window from another window, afte i close the child modal window i am trying to refresh the parent but i am getting retry/cancel popup, i tried a lot of things to avoid but i can't get rid of this popup :-( is there any way i can avoid this popup? I would really appreciate your help

Thanks
Faisal

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some of the code surrounding this issue.  That way it will be easier to see what the problem might be.

Comment: You seem to be talking about an error dialog with retry/cancel; what does the dialog say?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to bind an OnClickClient javascript function to the button who close the modal popup to manually call a PostBack to the server ?

```
function fnClickOK(sender, e) { 
__doPostBack(sender,e); 
}
```

that's the function you must include in your code and you can bind the button in the code behind like that

```
yourButton.OnClientClick = String.Format("fnClickOK('{0}','{1}')", yourButton.UniqueID, "");
```

Like that, the postback should occur and because of the page reload all Modal will be hided.

Good Luck!